# Hosting a single page React app on GitHub Pages - getting a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I am learning React and want to host my little single page project on gh-pages to include it on my portfolio but instead of the actual app there's just a blank page:

https://bopcho.github.io/my-chat-app/

here's my repo: https://github.com/bopcho/my-chat-app

what causes that and how can I fix it?

I tried hosting from different branches, no success.

Comment: For React, GH Pages is not the best one. You can try Netlify or Vercel. The process of deploying here is easier than gh-pages. You can follow the blog below.
https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/

Comment: I tried both but I get 404 code not found. So I tried changing the root a couple of times but it's still the same

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

You have to export a production version of your app. In your development environment, once you run `npm run dev` you will be able to see the result.

## Possible Solutions

You have to run `npm build` and the push your code again. The files of your final project will be at the `dist` directory. Then, you can go to https://bopcho.github.io/my-chat-app/dist/

You can then add a redirect HTML file in your main/root project directory. The file could look like this one...

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            window.addEventListener("load", () => {
                window.location.href = "dist/";
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

There are other ways to make redirect and this is not, by any mean, the best one. It was just the most convenient on to me!

Another option is what Vite have added already, run `npm run deploy`. I am not 100% sure what that will do since I haven't used it, but seemingly, it will create a production version and deploy it to github pages automatically.

### Useful links

https://blog.logrocket.com/deploying-react-apps-github-pages/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/deployment-of-react-application-using-github-pages/